# PHP Codeigniter batch update on some field failed

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a table on html like this : 
**VIEW**

```
<table id="tableReport" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>DAMAGE</th>
        <th>REPAIR</th>
        <th>REMARKS</th>
        <th>MANHOUR</th>
        <th>MATERIAL</th>
        <th>A / C</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="68" placeholder="68" disabled="" name="name_type">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Cleaning" placeholder="Cleaning" disabled="" name="name_item">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Certificate" placeholder="Certificate" disabled="" name="name_item">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Broken" placeholder="Broken" disabled="" name="name_damage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Blast&Paint" placeholder="Blast&Paint" disabled="" name="name_repair">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="AAAAAA" placeholder="AAAAAA" disabled="" name="name_remarks">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="10.00" placeholder="10.00" disabled="" name="name_damage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="material" class="form-control" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="A/C" class="form-control" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="69" placeholder="69" disabled="" name="name_type">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Cleaning" placeholder="Cleaning" disabled="" name="name_item">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Exterior" placeholder="Exterior" disabled="" name="name_item">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Modified" placeholder="Modified" disabled="" name="name_damage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Replace" placeholder="Replace" disabled="" name="name_repair">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="BBBBB" placeholder="BBBBB" disabled="" name="name_remarks">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="10.00" placeholder="10.00" disabled="" name="name_damage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="material" class="form-control" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="A/C" class="form-control" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**
I got all the value on those table using this jquery :

```
$('#tableReport').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
        var row_data = [];
        $(':input', this).each(function () {
            row_data.push($(this).val());
        });
        table_data.push(row_data);
 });
```

The result looked like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 68
        [1] => Cleaning
        [2] => Certificate
        [3] => Broken
        [4] => Blast&Paint
        [5] => AAAAAA
        [6] => 10.00
        [7] => a
        [8] => b
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 69
        [1] => Cleaning
        [2] => Exterior
        [3] => Modified
        [4] => Replace
        [5] => BBBBB
        [6] => 10.00
        [7] => c
        [8] => d
    )

)
```

This array is used to update_batch in my table.

```
mysql> select * from tb_repair_detail;
+-----------+--------------------+------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+------+
| DETAIL_ID | REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID | ITEM | DAMAGE_ID | REPAIR_ID | REMARKS | MANHOUR | MATERIAL | AC   |
+-----------+--------------------+------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+------+
|        68 |                 43 | 01   | 01        | 30        | AAAAAA  |   10.00 |     NULL | NULL |
|        69 |                 43 | 03   | 16        | 45        | BBBBB   |   10.00 |     NULL | NULL |
+-----------+--------------------+------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

SO, AJAX get call the controller take this action :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/c_admin/update_json_detail'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            POST_ARRAY: table_data
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (obj) {
            console.log(obj);
        }
    });
return false;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update_json_detail(){
   $execute = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
   /*CODE TO INSERT BATCH*/
   $callback = $this->m_admin->update_eir_to_cost($execute, execute_first_index[0]);
}
```

This is the **model**.

```
public function update_eir_to_cost($data, $id) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->update_batch('tb_repair_detail', $data, $id); 
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
        echo "Error Updating";
    }
}
```

My big problem is, I want to use update batch. But, I just want to just update manhour and ac field. I really stuck for days, any help it so appreciated

**UPDATE**
Huge Thanks for Mr.Sultan.
Now, My code is looked like this :

```
public function update_json_detail() {
    $post_data = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
    $execute = array();
    foreach ($post_data as $data) {
        $execute[] = array(
            'ID'=> $data['0'],
            'MATERIAL' => $data['7'],
            'AC' => $data['8']
        );
    }

    /* CODE TO INSERT BATCH */
    $callback = $this->m_admin->update_eir_to_cost($execute);
}
```

My model get some trouble, coz, I need three parameters to update_batch

```
public function update_eir_to_cost($id, $material, $ac) {
    $data = array(
        "MATERIAL" => $material,
        "AC" => $ac
    );

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where($id);
    $this->db->update_batch('tb_repair_detail', $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
        echo "Error Updating";
    }
}
```

Thanks for the solution

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:batch-file]?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, replace your function with this one:

```
public function update_json_detail(){
   $post_data = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
   $execute = array();
   foreach($post_data as $data){
   $execute[] = array(
    'MANHOUR' => $data['6'],
    'AC' => $data['8']
   ); 
   }
   /*CODE TO INSERT BATCH*/
   $callback = $this->m_admin->update_eir_to_cost($execute, execute_first_index[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to cope with a problem, but we have to select only smartest method.

You need to select only required elements than push in array and post them.
Please provide name attributes to input elements and in view (html) and in jQuery place check to select your required elements. Don't change anything in model and controller.

**Step # 1** 
    Input element should have name attribute.

`<input class="form-control" type="text" value="10.00" placeholder="10.00" disabled="" name="MANHOUR">
    <input id="A/C" name="A/C" class="form-control" type="text" value="11111">`

**Step # 2**
    JQUERY  -- Where you get values place following code instead of this `row_data.push($(this).val());`.

```
if($(this).attr("name")==='name_type' || $(this).attr("name")==='MANHOUR' || $(this).attr("name")==='A/C'){
row_data.push($(this).val());}
```